# How to use hands free bluetooth with React Native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

We're trying to use the library react-native-ble-plx (https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) inside an app made to be used in a car.

We want to listen to incoming audio messages with the car's bluetooth and record the radio at the same time (with the phone mic).

Problem is, we seem to be unable to record radio and use bluetooth at the same time because of A2DP protocol.

We believe hands free protocol might be a solution, I couldn't find any information about its use with react native, any idea?

Thanks!